# "View not defined" error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm learning Laravel, and I'm trying to create a form that list the cars in a cars table and if clicked, sends into another form which is based on a DB query that returns the data of the chosen car, which is identified with the modelesc variable. This form sends the data to a "orders" table. But I keep getting this error "Action App\Http\Controllers\orders not defined." on catalog.blade.php

This is the code that I have made.

CarController

```
function catalog() {
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->get();
    return view('catalog', compact('cars'));
}

function orders($modelesc) {
    $cars = DB::select('select * from cars where Model = modelesc');
    return view('orders', compact('cars'));
}
```

Catalog.blade.php

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden(modelesc, $car->Model) !!}
{!! Form::submit($car->Model) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

@endforeach

Orders.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'index', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
{!! Form::text(Model, $modelesc) !!}
{!! Form::hidden(users_id, Auth::user()->id) !!}
{!! Form::hidden(Fabrication_date, date(Y-m-d)) !!}
{!! Form::select('colour', [
    @foreach($colours as $colour)
        '$colour->Colour' => '$colour->Colour'
    @endforeach
]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden(Order_status_id, '1' !!}
```

{!! Form::close() !!}

This is the structure of the table 'orders'. The _id come from other tables, and I want to fill some values of the forms with this id's.

```
id, 
users_id, 
Model, 
Fabrication_date, 
Colour_id, 
Order_status_id
```

Comment: What version of Laravel and Form library are you using? I think you should declare the action as Controller@method.

Comment: Show us your whole catalog.blade.php please. You're probably calling something like `<a href="{{ action(someBrokenString) }}">...</a>` somewhere

Comment: Im acessing catalog through an index page: <a href="catalog"><h2>Catalog</h2></a> as for catalog.blade.php i have shown virtually the entire page. The rest is just this. The layout and the car count:  @extends('layouts.layout') 
<b>On this page ({{ $cars->count() }} cars)</b>

Comment: Can you share your routes file ?

Comment: Please do not add [closed] or [solved] devices to your titles, we do not do that here. We prefer that home-made tags are avoided as well - titles are best in plain English without any `Laravel -` or so forth at the start. Titles work well if they are posed as a question ending in a question mark.

Comment: If you could run your posts through a spelling checker that would be good too. We do not require perfect writing here, but it saves editors some work if you pay attention to case and spelling. When referring to yourself as "I" it is always a capital letter, even in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not know where to find the action `orders`, because you did not specify a controller (see the thrown exception: it is looking for some class named `orders` in the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\`). To do so, you just need to replace
`{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}`
with
`{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}`

If you want to use a route instead (e.g. you have defined a route named `orders` which links to a Controller action) you need to replace `action` with `route` in the `Form::open` method:
`{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}`.

Comment: No, that doesnt work. Neither using "{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'CarController@orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}" nor "{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'orders', 'method' => 'GET')) !!}" works. If i use the latter option it gives: "Route [orders] not defined"

Comment: Hi, what error message do you get when using the CarController@orders variant? Regarding the route variant: of course you need to define the route "orders" first, before you can use it that way (e.g. add `Route::get('your/url/to/orders', 'CarController@orders')->name('orders');` to your routes/web.php file).

Comment: If you specify the controller action you still need to have a route defined to that controller action.

Comment: yes, i have always had this route: Route::get('orders', 'carController@orders'); if i choose the first option i get: Action App\Http\Controllers\CarController@orders not defined.

Comment: Your route definition just defines that when requesting the url www.domainToYourApp.com/orders, the action "orders" of the "robotController" will be executed. But you did not specify a name for this specific route. This name is the one that is referenced by the value for the "route" parameter in the "Form::open" call. To add a name to your route just append "->name(nameOfTheRoute)" to it, so in your case: Route::get('orders', 'robotController@orders')->name('orders');

Comment: @Adato Just saw your edit: is your CarController really named that way? In your posted route definition the first letter of "carController" is uncapitalized - is this the case for your controller definition? If so, please try to change 'action' => 'CarController@orders' to 'action' => 'carController@orders'. It would really help if you could add the complete code of your CarController to your start post.

Comment: I have changed the first letter of "car" in the Route::get('orders', 'carController@orders')->name('orders') to uppercase: Route::get('orders', 'CarController@orders')->name('orders')...it now gives   the message: Use of undefined constant modelesc - assumed 'modelesc'

Comment: You need to put quotation marks around "modelesc" in your form definition: from {!! Form::hidden(modelesc, $car->Model) !!} to {!! Form::hidden('modelesc', $car->Model) !!}.

Comment: Ok. Now the catalog.blade.php works. I have put ($modelesc=null) in the CarController because i was getting a missing argument 1. Now im getting the message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'modelesc' in 'where clause' . But i have never indicated modelesc a column!!

Comment: Great that you made progress! Because this SQL issue is a new one, I would suggest you close this question and open up another one regarding this new problem. But because I don‘t want to let you down here: for "modelesc" in your sql query ('select * from cars where Model = modelesc') there is no indication that this should be handled as a variable by php, so this query is exactly like you defined it executed in MySQL. And in mysql the value "modelesc" is interpreted as a column. You need to add the "$"-prefix, to tell PHP that this is a variable and should be replaced by the value of $modelesc